# How do I figure out the format for struct.unpack (because I didn't pack in Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a C pipe client (pulled directly from the CallNamedPipe example found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that, if given the string "first", sends the following message to my Python pipeserver:

```
b'f\x00i\x00r\x00s\x00t\x00\x00\x00'
```

The [struct documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#struct) gives examples where I did both the packing and unpacking in Python. That means I know the format because I explicitly specified it when I called `struct.pack`.

Is there some way for me to either a) infer the format from the above output or b) set the format in C the same way I do in Python?

Here's the relevant client code:

```
    LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe");
    LPTSTR lpszWrite = TEXT("first");
    fSuccess = CallNamedPipe( 
          lpszPipename,        // pipe name 
          lpszWrite,           // message to server 
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C code is not writing a struct to the pipe, it is writing a null-terminated string encoded as little-endian UTF-16 text, which is produced by the [TEXT() macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you compile your Windows program in Unicode mode for an Intel CPU.  Python knows how to decode these strings without using the struct module.  Try this:

```
null_terminated_unicode_string = data.decode('utf-16le')
unicode_string = null_terminated_unicode_string[:-1]
```

You can use `decode('utf-16')` if your python code is running on the same CPU architecture as the C program that writes the data.  You might want to read up on python's [unicode codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode).

EDIT:  You can infer the type of that data by knowing how UTF-16 and Windows string macros work, but python cannot infer it.  You could set the string encoding in C the same way you would in python if you wanted to write some code to do so, but it's probably not worth your time.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> b'f\x00i\x00r\x00s\x00t\x00\x00\x00'.decode('utf-16le')
u'first\x00'
```

["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Why utf-16le? is it because of how I declared the variable in C? I was playing around and found that 'utf-16' (no le) also worked.

Comment: Because if it was big-endian you'd have `b'\x00f\x00i\x00r\x00s\x00t\x00\x00'` instead.